# Multiple SELECT in the same query which overwrite each-other's result

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Sorry for the confusing title, better go straight to the code:

Sample table:

```
|     key    |    value  |    MainLanguage     |     SubLanguage     |
|    mLangID |      5    |       default       |         en          |
|    mLangID |      3    |         esES        |         en          |
|    mTitle  |  Title    |       default       |         en          |
|    mTitle  |  Título   |         esES        |         es          |
```

I want to avoid using these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM translation.strings WHERE MainLanguage = 'esES' AND lang='es'
SELECT * FROM translation.strings WHERE MainLanguage = 'esES' AND lang='en'
SELECT * FROM translation.strings WHERE MainLanguage = 'default' AND lang='en'
...
```

and combine them into one, but make sure the result of the first query will not get overwritten by the results of the second one, and so on. Or, if it's easier, the reverse (Second query overwrites first query's results, 3rd overwrites 2nd query, etc)

Comment: `UNION` / `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `union all` with `where` clause to prioritize the results.  I'm guessing you want one row per `key`.  If so, this might work

```
SELECT *
FROM translation.strings s
WHERE MainLanguage = 'esES' AND lang = 'es'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM translation.strings s
WHERE MainLanguage = 'esES' AND lang = 'en' AND
      NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from translation.strings s2
                  where s2.key = s.key and s2.MainLanguage = 'esES' AND s2.lang = 'es'
                 )
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM translation.strings s
WHERE MainLanguage = 'default' AND lang = 'en' AND
      NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from translation.strings s2
                  where s2.key = s.key and
                        (s2.MainLanguage = 'esES' AND s2.lang = 'es' or
                         s2.MainLanguage = 'esES' AND s2.lang='en'
                        )
                 );
```

As a note:  there are easier ways of solving this in other databases.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL to combine results this will not remove duplicate rows.